# Cannot access, не могу заимплементить интерфейс

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Столкнулся с проблемой, не могу заимплементить интерфейс классу, помеченному аннотацией @Service, причем в другом проекте у меня с этим проблем не было.
Это, кстати говоря, не единственная странность. Я не могу просто заимпортить com.instahipsta.restService.services.UserService, приходится импортировать весь пакет.

```
package com.instahipsta.restService.impl;

import com.instahipsta.restService.domain.User;
import com.instahipsta.restService.repo.UserRepo;
import com.instahipsta.restService.services.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

Вот сам интерфейс:

package com.instahipsta.restService.services;

```
import com.instahipsta.restService.domain.User;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserService {

    List<User> findAll();
}
```

Вот что мне говорит идея:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее большое спасибо за ответы

Comment: У вас методы все реализованы с указанного интерфейса? Часто похожее выдает, если в интерфейсе метод прописан, а в сервисе не реализован.

Comment: Да, реализованы, и ошибка другая в таком случае была бы

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, проблема была в IDEA, удалил интерфейс и создал его через шорткаты(при том что до этого ребилдил проект и это не помогло), и никаких ошибок.